# How to create an abstraction layer between Form fields and the Model when adding a new record?

Tags: django-models, django-views, django-forms

In Django, when you want to code a form+view+HTML to create a new record for a model, online guides all steer you to the direct approach.  That is, use a `ModelForm` and a `CreateView` to expose all the fields and let the user specify each value directly.

But what if -- for purposes of usability and data integrity -- you need an abstraction layer between the displayed form elements, and the record which is ultimately inserted in the model?  Say for example,

- my_model.field_1 needs to be a concatenated string built from user-selected records (dropdown box selections), where the entries in those two dropdowns are based on records in my_other_model1 and my_other_model2
- my_model.field_2 and my_model.field_3 need to be obtained implicitly from the user-selected record from my_other_model1. Specifically, they are assigned to match the values of my_other_model1.field_7 and my_other_model1.field_9
- my_model.field_4, an integer, needs to be the sum of the lengths of strings entered in two separate TextFields that don't directly tie to any model
- my_model.field_5 and my_model.field_6 don't require any abstraction; the user can just enter their values directly in TextFields on the form

As a novice in Django I'm having a very hard time working out even a basic approach for this sort of use case.  I've spent days fiddling with JavaScript event handling and storing calculated values in read-only form fields, but it seems like there should be a much cleaner approach.

*(Note: the above bullet points are just generalized examples of the sort of functionality I need, not the actual application requirements I'm trying to code.)*

Comment: Ok I deleted my answer. I did not read closely enough to realize you are talking about checks on **different** models. I guess the [Constraints reference](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/constraints/#module-django.db.models.constraints) is what you are looking for. Never used it myself though but hope the link might be of help already!

Comment: Thanks, but constraints are not relevant to my question.  What I need is the ability to create an entire layer of calculations & custom logic that sits in between the form field entries, and the data entered into the new record for `my_model`.

Comment: I see. What dissuades you from putting that logic into the form and the view? Because that is the layer between form field entries and the database. I right now cant tell if I might be too less experienced to understand the question or if you might not know about the "defaults" of django.

Comment: Please carefully read the bullet points for examples of the sort of things I need to do.  I assume you can create your own form entry widgets and then process/combine/alter those widget inputs to generate the model field data, but I cannot find any examples to show the means to do it.

Comment: Decide for one of your examples and I'll give you the code for it. All of them is too much.

Comment: As I stated in the note at the end, the examples are arbitrary.  I am simply looking for a general approach that would support any or all of them.  You can choose any of the examples you wish and it will be sufficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this is not what you were hoping for, but my answer is: The abstraction layer "between user input and the database" are the form and the view.
If the usage of default `ModelForm` and `CreateView` is too basic for you, then you can overwrite their behaviour to your liking via inheritance.

```py
# models.py
class MyModel(models.Model):
    field1 = 
    field2 = 
    field3 = 
    field4 = 
    field5 = 

class OtherModelOne(models.Model):
    field7 = 
    field9 = 

class OtherModelTwo(models.Model):
    field1 = 
    field2 = 
    
    
    
# forms.py
class MyModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    # task 1 & 2
    choice_of_other_models1 = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=OtherModelOne.objects.all())
    choice_of_other_models2 = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=OtherModelOne.objects.all())
    
    # task 3
    textfield1 = forms.CharField()
    textfield2 = forms.CharField()
    
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        
        # don't display field1, field2, field3 and field4 and disable userinput for it
        field1 = self.fields.get('field1')
        field1.disabled = True
        field1.widget = HiddenInput
        # [...]
    
    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super().clean()
        
        # task 2
        cleaned_data['field2'] = cleaned_data.get('choice_of_other_models1').field7
        cleaned_data['field3'] = cleaned_data.get('choice_of_other_models2').field9
        
        # task 3
        cleaned_data['field4'] = len(cleaned_data.get('textfield1')) + len(cleaned_data.get('textfield2'))
        return cleaned_data
```

I know it might be a lot to take, so lets tackle this in words:

You have your model and two other models. You want to create `MyModel`. For its creation, as defined in your tasks, you actually do not need to visualize field1 to field4 because they are dependend on other factors and get not assigned directly.
Therefore you disable and hide them for userinput. You could do that already in the model with `hidden=True` but above you'll find how to do it in the forms `__init__()`method.

It is a ModelForm, so field5 and field6 can assigned directly by the user as you know already to do. But since all the other fields are related on parameters external to `MyModel` you want to add more fields manually.
These are here called `choice_of_other_models1` and `textfield1` and so on.
Inside of the `clean` method you can assign and redefine and modify all of your data inside of the dictionary `cleaned_data`.

Remember: If you need this functionality in multiple views it is better to put all that logic inside of the form. If on the other hand you need a more general creation of `MyModel` and this logic is only needed for this specific view, then of course you should put this logic to your view.
This decision has to be done on reusuability.

I understand that my code above is not a copy paste and it works solution, but I hope I could make my point clear: The abstraction layer you are talking about are the forms and the views. By inheritance it is reusuable and configurable to your needs.

Try to tackle one of your examples. I'm happy to help further in case you then hit a roadblock with specific (potentially buggy) code.

Comment: Thanks very much, this is exactly the assist I needed.  I wasn't sure *whether* (let alone *how*) it was possible to populate ModelChoiceField controls placed on one ModelForm/CreateView, using data from a different model -- this gives me a concrete example.  Similarly it shows where & how I can code in the extra logic of the examples I was describing.

Answer (score 0):

"but it seems like there should be a much **clean**er approach"

Depending on what you are using you can define `clean()` methods. Dealing with a `ModelForm` you can implement the `clean()` method to the model, dealing with a "normal" `Form` you can implement the `clean()` method to the form itself.

You can have field specific clean methods or general clean methods.

Example specific clean method:

```py
# models.py
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)

    def clean_name(self):
        if len(self.name) < 5:
            raise ValidationError({'name': "This is name is too short"})

# forms.py
class ProductForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        # [...]
```

This checks if the name is longer than 5 characters.
After checking for `form.is_valid()` you can deal with `form.cleaned_data['name']`. Data that "survives" to this point automatically went through that `clean()` procedure. In case the `ValidationError` gets triggered the form is invalid and normally you would want to display the error to the user. The error is here stored inside of the bound form field and can be specifically accessed by `{{ form.name.errors}}`
Please read [Cleaning a specific field attribute](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-a-specific-field-attribute)

If you on the other hand need to check on multiple fields, because they are interacting, you should aim for the general `clean()`.

```py
# models.py
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    second_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super().clean()
        name = cleaned_data.get("name")
        second_name = cleaned_data.get("second_name")

        if name and second_name:
            if len(name) < len(second_name):
                raise ValidationError(
                    "Name has to be longer than Second Name!"
                )


# forms.py
class ProductForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        # [...]
```

This clean method checks if the name is longer than the second name and does not accept the form if that is not the case.
Please read [Cleaning and validating fields that depend on each other](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-and-validating-fields-that-depend-on-each-other)

If the question can not be handled by the form alone, then ship the functionality to the view.

Comment: Thanks again but you are misunderstanding the question entirely.  The point is not to "clean" or "filter" the user inputs to make them valid.  As explained in the bullet points, it is to perform *extra* logic and *extra* calculations.  I need to do things like combine 2 form entries into 1 model field, or extrapolate 1 form entry to obtain 2 other model fields, and so on.